# How to optimize below code to find the duplicate record county using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to optimize below code to find the duplicate record county using pandas dataframe

```
        for Duprng in range(7):
            if (df['Name'].iloc[data_row] == df['Name'].iloc[Rowcnt]):
               TtlDup = TtlDup + 1
            Rowcnt = Rowcnt + 1 
        print(TtlDup)
```

Name
1.Rahul
2.Ravi
3.Rahul
4.Raja
5.Ram
6.Sam
7.Teju
8.Guru
9.Rajith
10.Yaj

Comment: Sample data please.

Comment: Please provide more detail to your question

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to find duplicates: `DataFrame.duplicated('column_name')`

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'name': 'John'}
b = {'name': 'Terry'}
c = {'name': 'John'}
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b, c])

print(df)
print('\n')

df['duplicated'] = df.duplicated('name')

print('All duplicates: ')
print(df)

print('\n')

print('Count: ')
print(df['duplicated'].value_counts()) # Counts the number of False (not duplicated) and True (duplicated)
```

Output:

```
    name
0   John
1  Terry
2   John


All duplicates: 
    name  duplicated
0   John       False
1  Terry       False
2   John        True


Count: 
False    2
True     1
Name: duplicated, dtype: int64
```